# Proof re Dedekind groups.

Tags: abstract-algebra

This should be simple, but for some reason I'm stuck on this problem from Herstein's Abstract Algebra book:

If group G is a Dedekind group, prove that for all a,b in G, $ab=b^ja$, where j is a positive integer.

I don't see why b would be cyclic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a,b \in G$.

Consider the cyclic subgroup $B = \langle b\rangle$.

Since $G$ is a Dedekind group, $B$ is a normal subgroup of $G$.

It follows that $aba^{-1} \in B$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&aba^{-1}\in B\\[4pt]
\implies\;&aba^{-1}=b^j,\;\text{for some integer j}\\[4pt]
\implies\;&ab=b^ja,\;\text{for some integer j}\\[4pt]
\end{align*}

Note: In the above proof, $j$ is only shown to be an integer (not necessarily positive).

Comment: If B is cyclic, then for successive positive values of j you'll get every possible b in B so it seems positivity IS guaranteed, no?

Comment: No, since $B$ need not be finite.

Comment: Right, of course.

Comment: If you look at the exercise, it didn't require $j$ to be positive.

Comment: But let me amend my comment "since $B$ need not be finite". In the proof I posted, I don't try to claim that $B$ is finite, so without that, I can't claim $j$ can be chosen as positive. However, since $G$ is Dedekind, all elements of $G$ do, in fact, have finite order (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_group). But as I noted, Herstein's exercise only requires $j$ to be an integer.